# Variables de sesion PHP

Tags: php, session

Estoy intentando hacer un login que lleva a varias páginas si te logueas.
Quiero poner una variable de sesión, pero no se muy bien como funciona.
Tengo este código:

```
<?php

session_start();
require('../Funciones/funciones.php');

////Datos db
$usuario = "usu";
$password = "pass";
$servidor = "ser";
$basededatos = "db";

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

// Valor por defecto en PHP
// Muestra todos los errores menos las notificaciones
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

// Muestro todos los errores
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(-1);

// Muestro todos los errores, incluso los estrictos
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

// No muestra ningún error
error_reporting(0);

// También se puede usar la función ini_set
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

 //// Recoger variables ////
$usuarior = $_POST['usuarior'];
$contrasenya = $_POST['contrasenya'];


////Crear conexion
$conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password)
or die("No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos");

////Seleccionar db
$db = mysqli_select_db($conexion, $basededatos)
or die("Uppppss! No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos");

////Establecer y realizar consulta
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

//variables para iniciar sesión
$encontrado=false;
$rolElegido = "";


//Recorrer las filas para ver si usuario y contraseña coinciden e iniciar sesión o no
if(isset($usuarior) && isset($contrasenya)){
    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){

        $filaUsuario = $fila["usuario"];
        $filaContrasenya = $fila["contrasenya"];

        if($usuarior == $filaUsuario && $contrasenya == $filaContrasenya){

            $_SESSION['usuarior'] = $usuarior;

            echo "<script>alert('Se ha conectado correctamente')</script>";
                $encontrado = true;
                $rolElegido = $fila["rol"];

                //Si usuario y contraseña coincide, elegir rol

                if($rolElegido == "administrador"){
                    echo "<script>window.location='../Administrador/index.php'</script>";
                }else{
                    echo "<script>window.location='../Usuario/index.php?usuarior=$usuarior'</script>";
                    }
                break;
                 //asisganar variables de sesion con el nombre de usuario y el roll

        }
    }//end while


    //Si susario y contraseña coinciden o no coinciden , hacer: 
    if ($encontrado == false){
        echo "<script>alert('Error al iniciar sesión. Usuario no identificado.')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.location='login.php'</script>";
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Iniciar sesión</title>
</head>
<body style="font-face: Verdana; font-size: 30px; background:url(color-degradado-fondos-degradados-multicolor-51200.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat">

    <div style = "margin-top: 200px; width: 400px; height:300px; background-color: white;margin-left: 34%; border: 1px solid #D0D0D0">
        <div align = "center">
            <h5 style = "color: #757474; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Registro de marcas</h5>
            <p style = "margin-top: -35px;color: #D0D0D0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight:600">Inicia sesión para editar, crear o eliminar marcas</p>
        </div>
        <form method="post" action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
                <label><input style = "margin-left: 10%; margin-top: 10px; width: 80%; height: 30px; text-align: center; font-size: 15px; color: #A3A3A3" type="text" required placeholder="Nombre de usuario" name="usuarior" id="usuarior"/></label>
                <label><input style = "margin-left: 10%; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px; width: 80%; height: 30px; text-align: center; font-size: 15px; color: #A3A3A3" type="password" required placeholder="Contraseña" name="contrasenya" id="contrasenya"/></label>
                <input style = "margin-left: 10%; margin-top: 5px; width: 80%; height: 30px; text-align: center; font-size: 15px; color: white; background-color: #04C4CC" type="submit" value="Iniciar sesión"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ésta es la función que intento usar para hacer las variables de sesión:

```
function verificar_session(){
    if(!isset($_SESSION['usuarior'])){
        echo "<script>window.location='../Login/login.php'</script>";
    }else{
        echo "Funciona";
    }
}
```

Y este código es un ejemplo de dónde llevaría si me logueo:

```
<?php

////Datos db
$usuario = "usu";
$password = "pas";
$servidor = "ser";
$basededatos = "db";

//session_start();
require('../Funciones/funciones.php');
verificar_session();
echo $_SESSION['usuarior'];

////Crear conexion
$conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password)
or die("No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos");

////Seleccionar db
$db = mysqli_select_db($conexion, $basededatos)
or die("Uppppss! No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos");

////Establecer y realizar consulta
$sql = "SELECT nombre FROM marcas";

?>
```

A ver si me podéis ayudar, que nunca he hecho esto de las variables de sesión, gracias.

Comment: Especifica un poco más que es lo que deseas hacer para que te podamos ayudar. Explica por ejemplo el comportamiento que quieres que tenga la aplicación para que la podamos comprender mejor.

Comment: Al loguear le das valores a las variables $_SESSION[''] y luego, en cada página, arriba del todo compruebas con un if, por ejemplo. if(isset($_SESSION['usuario']) (compruebas que no está vacía) sigues, else haces un exit imprimiendo un mensaje, por ejemplo. Explica un poco más qué quieres conseguir para ayudarte mejor

Comment: Deberías des comentar a cada página protegida la función `session_start();`, para que compruebe correctamente tu funcion `verificar_Session()`, ya que la función es correcto. La función `session_start()` debería ir al inicio de tu programa para evitar conflictos.

Comment: Aparte de lo que dice D.Bulten, y no relacionado con la pregunta en sí, este código de login es ineficiente: para comprobar un usuario, traes todos los usuarios de la bd y los vas comprobado uno a uno. Puede no ser importante si tienes pocos usuarios, pero conforme el número vaya creciendo el rendimiento se puede ver afectado considerablemente. Además, hay mucho código innecesario (p.e. los `error_reporting` supongo que son para pruebas, pero sólo haría falta uno), así como algunos problemas de seguridad (el id de sesión se debería renovar, las contraseñas no deberían estar en el fichero...)